# Deserialization by JSON.NET of a list of interfaces inside another class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I already surfed thorough other questions, but I can't solve this.

The JSON is the following

```
[
    {
        "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.AggregatorItem, UWP.Model",
        "UId": 17,
        "Name": "K2 BDB-INCON4-U",
        "IsPublished": true,
        "Items": [{
                "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.Item, UWP.Model",
                "IsPublished": true,
                "UId": 18,
                "OwnerUId": 17,
                "Name": "1: Root - I/O Modules K2 Switch 1",
                "UIdStreet": 1,
                "UIdArea": 1
            },
            {
                "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.Item, UWP.Model",
                "IsPublished": true,
                "UId": 19,
                "OwnerUId": 17,
                "Name": "2: Root - I/O Modules K2 Switch 2",
                "UIdStreet": 1,
                "UIdArea": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.AggregatorItem, UWP.Model",
        "UId": 41,
        "Name": "K3 SH2INDI424",
        "IsPublished": true,
        "Items": [{
                "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.Item, UWP.Model",
                "IsPublished": true,
                "UId": 42,
                "OwnerUId": 41,
                "Name": "1: Root - Switches K3 Switch 1",
                "UIdStreet": 1,
                "UIdArea": 1
            },
            {
                "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.Item, UWP.Model",
                "IsPublished": true,
                "UId": 43,
                "OwnerUId": 41,
                "Name": "2: Root - Switches K3 Switch 2",
                "UIdStreet": 1,
                "UIdArea": 1
            },
            {
                "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.Item, UWP.Model",
                "IsPublished": true,
                "UId": 44,
                "OwnerUId": 41,
                "Name": "3: Root - Switches K3 Switch 3",
                "UIdStreet": 1,
                "UIdArea": 1
            },
            {
                "$type": "UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.Item, UWP.Model",
                "IsPublished": true,
                "UId": 45,
                "OwnerUId": 41,
                "Name": "4: Root - Switches K3 Switch 4",
                "UIdStreet": 1,
                "UIdArea": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see I put the type thanks

```
TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
```

So, I can't understand why I can't deserialize as the following

```
var lstAggregatorItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AggregatorItem>>(tokenAggregators.ToString());
```

The class `AggregatorItem` has only interfaces, none implementation of Item since I want to work only with interfaces and no direct implementation

```
public class AggregatorItem : IAggregatorItem
{
    public int UId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsPublished
    {
        get { return Items.Any(i => i.IsPublished); }
    }
    
    public AggregatorItem()
    {
        Items = new List<IItem>();
    }

    public IList<IItem> Items { get; set; }

    public IItem GetItem(int itemUId)
    {
        return Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.UId == itemUId);
    }

    public void Remove(int itemUId)
    {
        var itemToRemove = Items.SingleOrDefault(i => i.UId == itemUId);

        if (itemToRemove == null)
            return;

        itemToRemove.Reset();
        Items.Remove(itemToRemove);
    }

    public void AddItem(IItem item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            item.Reset();
        }

        Items.Clear();
    }
}
```

So, is there something to teach to serializer "use this implementation of this class"? Because this exception is annoying me

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Could not create an instance of type UWP.Model.Management.VirtualCarPark.Item.IItem. Type is an interface or abstract class and cannot be instantiated. Path '[0].Items[0].IsPublished', line 10, position 22.

Comment: The Newtonsoft API does not know what class to use when deserializing this property `public IList<IItem> Items { get; set; }` because you are using an interface named `IItem` instead of an actual class.  The relevant code in Rehaan's answer is the `public List<Item> Items { get; set; }`. Notice the difference with your code (you used `IItem` and Rehaan `Item`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must pass a "model" instead of "AggregatorItem" here:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("$type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public int UId { get; set; }
        public int OwnerUId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int UIdStreet { get; set; }
        public int UIdArea { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("$type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public int UId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublished { get; set; }
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }


 var lstAggregatorItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(tokenAggregators.ToString());
```

Comment: I understoot but is it the only way? As I wrote I would like to keep interfaces without expose implementation. If there isn't other clever way I have to make another classes with another implementation without interfaces

Comment: @lunatic84. You could have two extra classes only for the json structure so your logic related yo your agregattor class would not break if the JSON changes later in the future. And to convert between the json classes and the agregator you could use automapper. If you want to use interfaces in the json related classes, maybe using a [CustomJsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)